# Как правильно сделать вывод умножения переменных введенных пользователем?

Tags: c#

Задали такое упражнение:

1. Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и перемножать их, пока он не напишет слово `«result»`.
2. Когда пользователь напишет слово «result», должен быть выведен итоговый результат и начат процесс заново.
3. Если пользователь напишет `«exit»` или `«quit»`, программа должна быть завершена (`break` внутри цикла).

Как я понял все действия должны происходить внутри цикла. Так вот ввод переменных пользователем я осуществил. Выход тоже. Но никак не могу понять, как правильно выводить умножение переменных, введенных пользователем.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число: ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    if (str == "result")
    {
          Console.WriteLine();// как здесь правильно сделать умножение переменных введенных пользователем
    }
    else if (str == "quit" || str == "exit") break;
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(a * b);`

Comment: Таким образом выводится умножение переменных 1 и 0 и получается 0. А мне нужно чтобы если пользователь вводит result происходило умножение всех введенных им переменных

Comment: "ввод переменных пользователем я осуществил" - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
int b = 1;
string buffer;
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число: ");
    //Считываем строку
    buffer = Console.ReadLine();
    if (buffer == "result") {
        //Выводим результат
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        //Начинаем процесс заново
        b = 1;
    }
    //Выходим с цикла, прекращая работу
    else if (buffer == "quit" || buffer == "result")
        break;
    else {
        //Пытаемся перевести строчку в целочисленный тип
        //Если перевод удачен, то умножаем наш результат на введенное число
        int t = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(buffer, out t))
            b *= t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. попробую обмозговать это. Я в принципе нашел в интернете ответ как это сделать, но во первых не хочу тупо копировать, во вторых там есть то что ещё не прошли на обучении, поэтому есть сложность в понимании. Вот как раз это выражение  Int32.TryParse(buffer, out t) ещё не объясняли. Ну погуглю сам что это. Спасибо.

Comment: Интересно. За что же кто-то проголосовал против? Просто за `c++`? Смешно)

Comment: Ответ надо давать на то языке, который соответствует тегам в вопросе, все верно.

Comment: @aepot не знаю как по мне мой код можно было понять и программисту `c#` как минимум комментарии есть. Так что душить за это глупо

Comment: Ну вам виднее..